# Cannot access web on running docker containers

Tags: docker

I have two containers, wds and apache. Both of them are running and have clear logs. I also checked if apache is running inside apache container and It is. My problem is that if I try to connect at localhost:80 which is the port that apache container listents to, I get only ERR_TIMED_OUT. Can you point me in which direction to look ? Containers were builded succesfully, no errors in logs, apache is running. I don't know where to look.

Answer (score 2):

did you expose the port in Dockerfile and used -p 80:80 while using docker run command?

There is a specific logic to be followed while running or interacting with containers.
I do not know what commands or arguments you want to use so I will put an example here with basic explanation assuming you want to run a container with exposed port 80 in terminal interactive

`docker run [container ID] -ti -p 80:80 /bin/bash`

*used commands:*

-t tty - allocate a terminal so you can directly interact with the docker command

-i - interactive - connects STDIN to the allocated terminal. Any command you enter after this will go to the terminal.

-p - binds port

https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

Comment: I have defined ports 80:80 and 443:443 in my docker compose file. If I try to run docker run -p 80:80 I get "docker run" requires at least 1 argument